# Automatically sum manually typed equation in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel, vba

I just wanted to know that I have some values written in Cell `J10` as shown in image and want to sum these values in cell `K10` cell.

To do so, I currently add them manually by typing `=1.25+1.25-1+.5` in cell `K10`.

Is there any way that cell `K10` automatically calculates the values entered in cell `J10` as shown in image, and cell `K10` automatically updates the total if I make any changes in values in cell `J10`?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHbF4.png)

Comment: I am a little confused are you saying K10 = J10 or are you saying that K10 should include J10 in its total but you intend to add numbers into J10? (Can you not put other numbers +J10 in K10?)

Comment: @QHarr - The second paragraph describes what the op is currently doing; he/she is looking for an alternative as per supplied image.

Comment: @Jeeped I know I am tired and I am probably also being dense. I was struggling with that image to understand what was going on. So probably my fault. It felt like they were saying everytime something was added in J10 then have K10 add that number so I wasn't sure why J10 wasn't part of a formula in K10. TBH I still don't get it but maybe a good night's sleep will fix that <ponders...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want to type the formula into J10 and have the result in K10 (per your narrative and image).

[image]

Go to Formulas, Defined Names, Name Manager and click New. Set up a new named range called `evalJ` with workbook scope and a Refers to: of,

```
=evaluate(column!$J1)
```

Click OK to create the name and exit the Name Manager.

Type your formula into J10 (e.g. 1.25+1.25-1+.5) without an equals sign. Put the following formula into K10,

```
=iferror(evalJ, "")
```

This can be used in any column to evaluate an equation in column J of the same row.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh... I should have read this first!

Comment: Yeah, I'm completely at a loss regarding the close votes and subsequent [on hold] status. Seems there were plenty of questions worse than this posted today.

Comment: Bro, you got my question absolutely right. and i wanted to do the same you have done and share the image. I follow all the instructions you said but this is not working for me. please help me. and i am sorry to all others for my bad communication.

Comment: Note that *column* is the name of the worksheet from your image, not a *column* on any single worksheet.

Comment: Try the workbook behind [this link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiKOYgfOUhMWnxXcXMFFCXLPG7vI) for comparison.

Comment: sorry for bothering you sir but how can i upload the image here so you can see where i am wrong and guide me please.

Comment: i have seen the file in the link. in this file i have some manual entries in "J" Column and "iferror" function in "E" column but all cells in E column are blank why result is not showing in Column E cells

Comment: You need to download the file and enable editing.

Comment: done it already sir.... cells with iferror function are blank they are not showing the sum results

Comment: You didn't 1. download 2. open 3. enable editing. I did this myself with an annonomous download to an alternate computer account to test and it worked fine.

Comment: i cant upload image here is there any other way to show you the image of the file you uploaded sir, i 1. download 2. open 3. enable editing follow the instructions as you said. but its not working for me. please tell me any other way to show you the image. thanks for your precious time and support i am great full to you.

Comment: That linked workbook already has everything working. I was hoping you could use it as an example.

Comment: the linked workbook is not working on my PC. maybe due to communication mistake i couldn't convey my issue properly. Thanks for your support Sir May God Bless you. you were very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use the following UDF

```
Function mySum(s As String) As Variant
 mySum = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest the opposite. `Function FT(mycell As Range)  // FT = mycell.Formula // End Function`

Comment: If it's working why not